# Why can't I use break in a C# ternary expression?

Tags: c#, break, ternary-operator

I am trying to convert the if else clause to a ternary within a while loop, however it's not allowing me to have a break after the question mark, pointing an error at the break as an invalid expression.

How would I go about turning this simple if else into a ternary like so.

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter 3 words seperated by spaces: ");
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    //input == "" ? break : ConvertToPascal(input);
    if (input == "")
        break;
    else
        ConvertToPascal(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: You found one of the important words already: *expression*. `break` is a *statement*. And statements in C# are not expressions (although many expressions can be used as statements as well, so the reverse can be true).

Comment: Ask yourself: How is the compiler supposed to assign `break` to the `input` variable?

Comment: what is the point of converting an `if` to a ternary? I can understand using it to inline simple value assignment, but when **flow logic** (e.g.  `break` is involved, using an `if`is much clearer than trying to inline a ternary.

Comment: There was a language proposal made.  https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/176

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't possible using the ternary operator, but you can simplify your code structure as follows:

```
string input;
do {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter 3 words seperated by spaces: ");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (input != "") {
        ConvertToPascal(input);
    }
} while(input != "");
```

Answer (score 7):

Because the ternary is **not** a shorter way to write an `if-else` structure, it's a short way to write an expression that picks one of two values based on some condition. `break` is a flow-control statement, not a value.

If it helps, think of:

```
someVar = cond ? a : b;
```

as of:

```
someVar = getValue(cond);
```